# Android Studio - Error Module not specified

Tags: java, android

i'm a newbie to Android/Java development and purchased a book Java Programming for Android Developers For Dummies, 2nd Edition.

This comes with a code samples section http://users.drew.edu/bburd/Java4Android/ (chapter 02_01) I understand the book is a few years old hence so the code samples will be. However, i'm having massive problems getting the code samples to run on Android Studio 4.1.2.

I can import the project and sync the Gradle files. When I do it appears with a green tick at the bottom. Oddly it says failed next to that with the following message.

```
Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage().
            The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
            To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
            Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 443 ms)
```

My build.gradle file is as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also if I try and run the project I see this screen [image: Error message]

[image: main screen]

I've read many posts with similar issues and worked through various fixes. None seemed to work so can anyone shed any light on what's happening please? I've also downloaded android studio on 3 different PC's incase its a bug of some sort.

Thank you

Comment: See the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409047/gradle-sync-failed-unsupported-method-syncissue-getmultilinemessage-androi

Comment: You must open the folder in android studio which is having [.gradel, .idea, app, gradel, build.gradel] folders and files in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should say the files in there are very outdated, and you will have very hard time, with every project. But if you still want to build the project here are a few things you can do.

look for the file `gradle-wrapper.properties` and update it with this

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

Then move to project level `build.gradle` file (there are two one inside app directory and one on the root directory, use the root directory)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then move to app level `build.gradle` and update it with this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.allyourcode.a02_01"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
}
```

And then sync the project and let Android studio do its magic.

Comment: thank you so much works fine. At least I can follow along with the book now. appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

As the stack traces say, you should upgrade your Gradle version. You are using an "old" book where the samples have been build with an old version of Android Studio that supports well that old version of Gradle. But 4.1 is a recent version and does not support well many old Gradle features.